# Find extremals of $B$ with respect to $R= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq y\}$, $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R} | 1 \leq x < 2\}$

Tags: relations, self-learning

I have to find minimal, maximal, smallest, largest, lub and glb of $B$
with respect to
$R= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq y\}$, where $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 1 \leq x < 2\}$

**Attempt**

1. Let $b$ be a minimal element of $B$. So $\neg \exists x \in B$ s.t. $(xRb \land x \neq b )$.
   So $\neg \exists x \in B$ s.t. $x\leq b$ and $x\neq b$. Now $x=1$ seems an option but they say $x \neq b$ which is not true here as $1$ is in $B$. So no minimal element
2. Similar reasoning as as above, so no maximal element because $2$ does not belong to the set.
3. Smallest element: Let $b$ be smallest element. So $\forall x \in B$ $bRx$, ie $b\leq x$. So $b=1$ is smallest element.
4. No largest element as $\forall x \in B$, $x \leq b$. $2$ seems to be a choice here  but it is not in the set.
5. G.L.B Here $1$ is glb as it's the smallest element also and in the set
6. L.U.B Here $2$ is lub as every element of $B$ is less than or equal to $2$

I am bit confused while doing all this. Please tell me if this is correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently $R$ is just the usual order relation... Why complicate?

Comment: I have just tried to apply definitions which i am reading for two days. I am not sure how to do this

Comment: Clearly, $1$ is minimal in $B$, and the only one, so it's the smallest and the glb

Comment: It's correct that $2$ is the lub, but your justification is only half way to it

Comment: @amrsa i know that maximal element if belonging to set is the LUB, what else is needed?

Comment: If maximal element is unique, nothing more is needed. But here, $2 \notin B$

Comment: i am not sure i understand you

Answer (score 1):

If you find a smallest element, then you should also have a minimal one. So either 1 or 3 is wrong.

The wrong one is 1; indeed, the number $1$ is the smallest element in $B$, because $1\in B$ and, for every $x\in B$, $1\le x$.

Now, if a set has a smallest element, it also have a (unique) minimal element.

There is no maximal element, because if $x\in B$, then also
$$
x'=\frac{x+2}{2}\in B
$$
and $x<x'$. Therefore there is no greatest element either, because it would also be maximal.

If a smallest element exists, it is also the greatest lower bound.

The lowest upper bound is $2$, but not just because $x\le 2$ for every $x$ in $B$, as this just shows $2$ is an upper bound.

You should prove that $2$ is less than or equal to any other upper bound. So, suppose $c$ is an upper bound for $B$, in particular $1\le c$. Suppose $c<2$; then $x=(c+2)/2\in B$ (why?) and $c<x$, a contradiction.

Comment: How to find minimal using definiton

Comment: From where did x +2 \2 come from?

Comment: $(x+2)/2$ is the mid point between $x$ and $2$. In order to find minimal elements from the definition, one usually finds the elements that are *not* minimal. Or you can make the conjecture that $1$ is minimal; it is, because if $x\in B$ and $x\le 1$, then $x=1$.

Comment: i have read some other defintion . see my 1st point

Comment: what is the difference between lower bound and smallest element ?